# Quiz game to guess player's zodiac sign

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a quiz game where the user answers some questions and at the end the game will assign a zodiac sign. So what I did:

- Created two different dictionaries, one to store each sign and the other one with the definition for each sign.
- Looped through all the questions.

Now I'm trying to get the highest score and display the sign and the definition, but I'm completely stuck.

Here is part of the problem:

```
# THIS IS THE 1ST DICTIONARY

scores = {
    "1 Aries": aries, 
    "2 Taurus": taurus, 
    "3 Gemini": gemini, 
    "4 Cancer": cancer, 
    "5 Leo": leo, 
    "6 Virgo": virgo, 
    "7 Libra": libra, 
    "8 Scorpio": scorpio, 
    "9 Sagittarius": sagittarius, 
    "10 Capricorn": capricorn, 
    "11 Aquarius": aquarius, 
    "12 Pisces": pisces
}

# THIS IS PART OF THE 2ND DICTIONARY (I won't copy everything here because it's too big)
zsigns_definition = {
    "Aries": "You could be Aries: March 21 - April 19. - Aries loves to be number one. Naturally, this dynamic fire sign is no stranger to competition. Aries dives headfirst into even the most challenging situations - and they will make sure they always come out on top! Aries is a passionate, motivated, and confident leader. Aries is easygoing and enjoy the company of all kinds of people.", 
    "Taurus": "You  ....."
}
```

And this is the code that tries to match the scores:

```
max_score = 0
for key in scores.keys():
    if max_score < scores["1 Aries"]:
        max_score = scores["1 Aries"]
        max_score = key
        print(max_score, zsigns_definition["Aries"])
```

This is where I'm stuck. I don't really know what to do to find the highest score and print it at the end? I'm trying to do this for each sign.

Comment: Karine - you don't say what the values in your first dictionary actually are defined as? If the issue is finding what range the user's score falls in, then what is key is defining those ranges - and it's not clear if you're doing that here?

Comment: If the values in your dictionary are just storing integers, and you want the largest key by value, you could use `max(scores, key=scores.get)`

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question so others can test the code in their answers.

Comment: thank you for all your answers. That helped me to clarify my question. I will try to put all my code here

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer under the assumption your dictionary `scores` is essentially equivalent to this.

```
scores = {
    "1 Aries": 0, 
    "2 Taurus": 1, 
    "3 Gemini": 2, 
    "4 Cancer": 3, 
    "5 Leo": 4, 
    "6 Virgo": 5, 
    "7 Libra": 6, 
    "8 Scorpio": 5, 
    "9 Sagittarius": 4, 
    "10 Capricorn": 3, 
    "11 Aquarius": 2, 
    "12 Pisces": 1
}
```

If this is true then to get the max key by value and print the definition from `zsigns_definition` you can do this:

```
zsigns_definition = {'Libra' : 'Definition of Libra goes here'}
number, sign = max(scores, key=scores.get).split()
print(zsigns_definition[sign])
```

Here is how you could do the same thing with a for loop:

```
max_value = 0
max_key = ''
for key, value in scores.items():
    if value > max_value:
        max_value = value
        max_key = key

number, sign = max_key.split()
print(zsigns_definition[sign])
```

Both will output:

```
Definition of Libra goes here
```

I noticed that in your for loop you print the max score every time it changes. I think that this is just an indentation error though due to the language, "**the highest** score and print **it** at the end".

Comment: The only thing I'd add here is that unless it's strictly necessary, we can simplify the code by fixing the original dictionary to drop the indexing number. (Thus avoiding the `split()`). Starting with good data structures is good!

Comment: @NathanielFord agreed or maybe OP could consider combining the two dictionaries into one of the form `{ 'sign' : {'score' : int, 'definition' : str } }` but who's to say without seeing a bit more of what's going on

Comment: I tried to fix it and now I'm getting a KeyError =/

Comment: Anyways thank you guys for your answers! I really appreciate it. I will try to see why I'm getting a keyError

Comment: @KarineUnderwood check for spelling mistakes in your second dictionary's keys (`zsigns_definition`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the values in the scores dictionary are numbers indicating the player score for each sign.

```
scores = {
    "1 Aries": 5, 
    "2 Taurus": 8, 
    "3 Gemini": 3
}

zsigns_definition = {
    "Aries": "You ...", 
    "Taurus": "You  ...",
    "Gemini": "You ..."
}
```

If so, you might add adding another variable to track the maximum key, and put the print statement outside of the loop.

```py
max_key = ""
max_score = 0
for key in scores.keys():
    if max_score < scores[key]:
        max_score = scores[key]
        max_key = key

number, sign = max_key.split() # Split the string on spaces
print(max_score, zsigns_definition[sign]) # prints "8 Taurus"
```

Here max_key.split() separates the text-string by spaces and puts it in a list. As it there will always be 2 items, we can unpack by putting two variable names separated by a comma on the left hand side.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this won't give a reasonable result. If the scores are strictly increasing, you will always set max_score to the last element in the score dictionary, and the max key to the same. What is this actually accomplishing?

Comment: It is a simple max-function written as a for-loop. I assumed the values of the scores-dictionary are integers representing the scores from the quiz. Why do you assume scores are strictly increasing? The values are not given. The problem in question is finding the highest score, and printing it.

Comment: If the issue is finding the largest value in the dictionary, then `max(scores, key=scores.get)` is sufficient. If the matter is matching some score x, earned by the player, to the most appropriate value in the dictionary... then this function won't work.

Comment: To addend: Without indicating what your assumption is about the state of the input dictionary, it's unclear why this will yield a correct result.

Comment: Updated and added the assumption. Yes, using max works also,. I decided to build on the code the OP submitted in their post.